# How to get the end event of CATransition/Animation?

Tags: iphone

My codes show below:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = duration
```

I hope to get the end event of CATransition/Animation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

CAAnimation (which CATransition is a subclass of) has the delegate method `animationDidStop:finished:` which you can use.

Set the delegate property and implement the method:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = duration;
transition.delegate = self;
//other settings...
//call addAnimation...

...

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    //do what you need to do when animation ends...
}
```

Comment: @Anna a bit old question, but Apple documentation said `An instance of CAAnimation should not be set as a delegate of itself. Doing so (outside of a garbage-collected environment) will cause retain cycles.` Is this not what you do in your answer? Or I'm wrong, explain please.

Comment: @flinth: No, `self` refers to the object that is creating `transition`, not to `transition` itself.  I believe what the docs mean is don't do something like `transition.delegate = transition;` .

Comment: @Anna oh, may be you right, anyway I'm don't see another way to implement this:) Thanks for explaining