# How to implement method: - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, catransition

I have two blocks of code (described also in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841120/how-to-get-the-end-event-of-catransition-animation?answertab=active#tab-top))

```
- (void)AnimateImage:(NSString*)direction{
    self.CurrentAnimal.image = [images objectAtIndex:image_nr];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:1.0];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    if([direction isEqualToString:@"left"]){
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    }
    else {
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    }
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
    [[self.CurrentAnimal layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

And

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    //do what you need to do when animation ends...
}
```

I know that I need to "set the delegate property and implement the method" to catch animationDidStop event but I'm not able to get it working.

Question - How do I set up my .h and .m files so that I'm able to use this method to execute code when CATransition animation stops?

Comment: What is not working? Are you not getting any the callbacks that you expect?

Comment: To me it seems that none of the code inside the animationDidStop method is executed when I'm pretty sure that the animation finished. That's why I'd be glad to get a full/simple implementation explanation with .m and .h files both set up.

Comment: I also replaced the fist block of code with real code @Unheilig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the delegate:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
....
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.0];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
```

Comment: could you also explain, what the setDelegation really is or does?

Comment: @KaarelKont-Kontson: Some classes have delegates. A delegate is simply an object that (usually) created the object and wishes to be notified/involved in the operations of the object for which it is the delegate.

Comment: @Linuxios So, in this case "self" refers to my ViewController and this setDelegate let's the program know, that animationDidStop method is in the ViewController class?

Comment: @KaarelKont-Kontson: spot on. You're basically telling the caanimation "I'm interested in what you're doing, notify me about changes and let me weigh in on your decisions".

Comment: Nice! Until now, I tried stuff similar to this: _@interface AnimalViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>_
To set the delegate :) - New in objective-c

Answer (score 1):

You first have to add the `Delegate` to the `CATransition` object you created like that

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate = self]; 
[animation setValue:animation.values.lastObject forKey:@"myAnimationKey"];
```

If you set a key for your animation, you can exactly check which animation ended. If you have just one animation, you don't need a specific key. If you set a key you can check which animation ended like that:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{

    if(anim == [animation.layer animationForKey:@"myAnimationKey"]){

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and the part about animationForKey!